# How to pass a Prop using Emotion CSS function

Tags: css, styled-components, emotion

I know I can pass **props** using [Emotion's](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction) `styled()`

i.e.

```
const Container = styled("div")<{ position: string }>`
  display: flex;      
  flex-direction: ${({ position }) => (position === "top" ? "column" : "row")};
  margin: ${({ position }) => (position === "top" ? "40px" : "0")};
`;
```

Can I/How can I do the same using Emotion's `css()` ?

i.e.

```
 const Container = css /*  doesn't work <{ position: string }>*/`
      display: flex;      
      flex-direction: ${({ position }) => (position === "top" ? "column" : "row")};
      margin: ${({ position }) => (position === "top" ? "40px" : "0")};
    `;
```

Comment: You should be able to pass a prop in a similar way
const Container = props => (<div css={{ *your styles here* }});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To better demonstrate the suggestion in my comment, here's an example using your code

```
 const Container = (position: string) => (
   <div css={{
     display: flex,     
     flexDirection: ${({ position }) => (position === "top" ? "column" : "row")},
     margin: ${({ position }) => (position === "top" ? "40px" : "0")}
   }}/>
 );
```

Emotion has some [examples of this](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop) on their site

Comment: Thank you - that's a great option.